# Audience-specific texts for our "Needs Attribution" custom close reason

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons

Last year (2020) saw some [changes to the question closure system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346638/) across the SE network. One of the changes was to introduce [**audience-specific texts for custom close reasons**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362584/), so that the OP, close voters, privileged users, **and the general public** can all get slightly different versions of the same essential explanation of why a question is unsuitable for the site. By default, all versions for existing close reasons are set to the same thing, since there didn't use to be any option to have different versions. Some sites [already](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1549/) changed their close reasons by creating separate texts as the system now allows. While Puzzling has the maximum of 3 site-specific custom close reasons, I’m [only doing the Needs Attribution one for now](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/14524?m=58612651#58612651).

The current text (taken from [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6407/) and clocking in at 395 characters) is:

> This looks like a puzzle you found elsewhere. For content you did not create yourself, **[proper attribution](/help/referencing)** is required. If you have permission to repost this, please edit to include (at minimum) where it came from, then vote to reopen. Posts which use someone else's content without attribution are generally **[deleted](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1348)**.

The following image shows the different boxes that can be filled by mods/CMs with different text. The first two appear in the close/flag dialogue *before* the post is closed; the last three appear in post notices *after* the post is closed.

Please note that there is a **500 character maximum** for what we can put in any of these boxes, and that’s counting formatting (such as links). With the exception of the first, which has a limit of 100 characters.

- The **Brief description** is the bold header for the close reason.
- The **Usage guidance** is what will appear in the close menu, advising people when to use the close reason.
- The **Close description** will be shown to everyone in the post notice and should be relatively short.
- The **Post owner guidance** appears in the post notice and is how the OP should fix the question (if possible).
- The **Privileged user guidance** is informative for the people with close privilege regarding what the close reason is.

[image]

---

### Let's get a consensus on what we should put in each box.

We need CM help to edit an existing close reason, so a clear meta consensus is essential, then we can [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) it and get them to help us making the necessary changes. I'm going to post an answer below with my proposed texts; please vote and give feedback or suggested improvements if necessary.

Comment: Looks good, implemented these changes! Thank you very much for the clarity of writing here - it helped a bunch when making these edits. FYI - made one small grammar change (switching a period and a parenthesis).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are the drafts I’ve come up with. Please comment with any improvements (and please don’t edit this post directly without consensus). Are there any other meta posts that might need to be summarized/linked here? (The links I’ve added are relatively recent ones because, well, that’s what I know of). See [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=attribution) for ideas.

### Brief description

The name shown to flaggers/close-voters when seeking an option in the close menu (currently **24**/100 characters):

> Needs proper attribution

### Usage guidance

The description shown to flaggers/close-voters after choosing this close reason (currently **208**/500 characters):

> This looks like a puzzle that was not created by the poster and/or one with insufficient attribution. [Proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7259) is required for non-original puzzles.

### Close description

The text shown to everybody, even non-users, viewing the closed question (currently **149**/500 characters):

> This question was **closed** for lacking [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7259). It is currently not accepting answers.

### Post owner guidance

The more detailed text shown, under the general close description, to the OP only when viewing their closed question (currently **447**/500 characters):

> This looks like a puzzle that you may have found elsewhere. For content that you did not create yourself, [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7259) is required. If you have permission to repost this, please edit to include (at a minimum) where it came from, then vote (or flag) to reopen. Posts which use someone else's content without attribution are generally [deleted](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1348).

### Privileged user guidance

The more detailed text shown, under the general close description, to any 3k+ rep user viewing the closed question (currently **247**/500 characters):

> If the poster has provided [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7259), either in an edit or a comment, please vote to reopen this question. (If the attribution was provided in a comment, please edit it into the question).

Comment: Perhaps the text of the 'proper attribution' link needs to be customized as well? It doesn't talk about puzzles at all, and it talks about answer-plagiarism, we are talking about questions. (Also it seems harsher than the 'owner guidance' ... "Hmm, this looks like it might be a puzzle you found somewhere else" versus "Plagiarism... CONFESS!!")

Comment: @deep, we can't edit that part of the Help Center - it's standardized across all sites ([reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259920/)).

Comment: If the generic /referencing page isn't enough to help educate, consider linking instead to a meta FAQ that asks "Why and how do I sufficiently attribute my question if it's not an original puzzle" and the answers explain that.

Comment: @Catija we don't have such a thing, unfortunately :/ It's spread across a bunch of meta posts; I've linked the ones I consider most important, and left room for more links if needed.

Comment: ... I mean... there's nothing preventing y'all from *creating* it, is there? If you want to ensure that people will be best able to understand how to fix the problem, making good guidance in post notices is a start but referencing excellent meta or help center pages is the other part of it. :) It's an ecosystem. (Also, note that you'll be linking to /referencing twice in the post notices for both the asker and high-rep users, since both the description and the other section are visible simultaneously.)

Comment: @Catija I would love it have it all, but I'm fighting one battle at a time here. More important to have proper post notices than an FAQ that few people will read. I was also worried about people getting meta fatigue, since this place can be pretty quiet. And yeah, there are double-links but it's an important one.

Comment: (On another point, there are some posts that *seem* like they would be good FAQs ([example](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4926/)) but they're either outdated or incomplete. There are quite a few wrinkles to the policy so that any FAQ would have some serious bloat)

Comment: Insisting on "proper attribution" is intended to not let people say "I found this on some website" or "I copied it from a book" and have that be sufficient. The /referencing link is useful guidance that, where available, an actual link and author's name are expected at SE; similarly, for offline sources, we expect enough information to be provided to serve as actual, functional attribution. We're looking for more than acknowledgement that "I didn't write this"; we want to give the creator their due. I am concerned that the "absolutely no attribution" guidance makes useless attributions OK.

Comment: @Rubio that was an (admittedly not good) attempt at summarizing [this answer](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7221/69582) - feel free to suggest a better one which adds in context like how it must be as much attribution as possible etc. Honestly I was really hoping for someone to suggest an edit there

Comment: I've been considering whether it would be worth it to create a central FAQ like Catija mentioned above... it's hard to squish the policy into 500 characters.

Comment: @bobble Consolidating existing commentary and answers about attribution and plagiarism into a single policy/FAQ is an excellent idea. I think it's important to note that [Rand al'Thor's good thoughts](/a/7221/30633) notwithstanding, it is not sufficient that people do not (appear to) claim someone else's work as their own, i.e. plagiarism; especially given that at PSE many people are creators themselves, we have a keen interest in ensuring that people actually provide proper attribution as well (which happens to also address the plagiarism issue). The policy/FAQ should reflect this.

Comment: @Rubio the proposed texts have now been rewritten to use the new attribution FAQ.

Comment: **Usage guidance**: "This looks like a puzzle not created by the poster and/or one with insufficient attribution. Proper attribution is required for non-original puzzles." →"This looks like a puzzle *that was* not created by the poster and/or one with insufficient attribution. Proper attribution is required for all puzzles not created by the poster."

Comment: **Post owner guidance**: "This looks like a puzzle *you may* have found elsewhere. For content that you did not create yourself, proper attribution is required. If you have permission to repost this, please edit to include (at minimum) where it came from, then vote (or flag) to reopen. Posts which use someone else's content without attribution are generally deleted."

Comment: **Privileged user guidance**: "If the poster has provided proper attribution, either *with* an edit or a comment, please vote to reopen *the question*. If the attribution was provided in a comment, please edit the attribution into the question."

Comment: I'm hoping the last few comments are helpful? I think they might smooth out the text, or .... it may just be my stylistic preference.

Comment: Also do we have a pathway for the poster, if they can prove/are adamant they made the puzzle themselves?

Comment: @Pureferret - if they say it's original from them then unless we have good reason to believe otherwise, the question is considered properly attributed (this is covered in the FAQ). As for the other things, it might be worth rewriting a bit to add in implied words/make sentences simpler, for the benefit of those not fluent. I'll look at it later since I'm going to be busy for a lot of today.

Comment: @bobble good to know about that, I should be more familiar with the FAQ. As for adding words/simplifying that sounds like a good idea, I'm following the post so should get updates whenever you get to it.

Comment: @Pureferret I've made most of the changes you requested, and also added a few other implied words while I was at it.

Comment: It looks great !

Comment: Thank you @bobble for pushing this forward; the FAQ and the textual revisions look good. This post has been [tag:featured] (thanks Gareth) for greater visibility and additional community feedback. After a suitable period for further input, I believe we should be in a good place to ask the CMs to make the new texts live.