# Can we have capture-the-flag tags?

Tags: feature-request

I like playing CTFs (capture the flag) which are mainly hacking games. I'd like also have some CTF style puzzles here (no hacking, just puzzles with things like OSINT and Crypto). I've noticed that there are no such tags on puzzling SE.

I enjoy playing hacking CTFs and I'd like to bring non-hacking CTF games to puzzling SE too. Since we already have the `cryptography` and `steganography` tags, I'd like to add the following tags:

`CTF`/`capture-the-flag`
`OSINT`

Answer (score 5):

I think you have things a little the wrong way around.

The tags are here to help people find puzzles, and there's only any point adding a tag once it has some puzzles to refer to. If you have (or can make) some good CTF-y puzzles, then make them and post them; if this turns out to be a genre of continuing interest, *then* we may need a tag or tags to describe puzzles in the genre.

One word of warning: your question uses the word "game" a couple of times; there's a difference between a *puzzle* and a *game*, and not all games are puzzles; puzzles are on topic here but games-that-aren't-really-puzzles aren't. The dividing line can be blurry, and different people take different views of exactly where it is. I don't know what sort of thing you have in mind and so can't really advise on whether it's likely that it'll be seen as insufficiently puzzly; the best thing is probably for you to make one and post it and see what the community makes of it.

Oh, one *other* word of warning: we do sometimes get things posted here that appear to be challenges from contests that are running elsewhere. It doesn't sound as if that's what you have in mind, but just to be clear: PSE [doesn't accept questions from ongoing contests](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1674/questions-from-on-going-contests). (There's an exception for contests with no closing date, but usually CTFs don't go on for ever.)

So, in summary:

- I don't think we need new tags yet.
- If you want to post some puzzles of this sort, you should do so and see how they go down.
- If we end up having a substantial number of such puzzles here, *then* we may need some tags for them.

Comment: I'd like to do a game/puzzle where the player as to go around the internet (like with google, pastebin, twitter, etc) to find pieces of data hinted in the post. Does that sound like a viable puzzle?

Comment: Maybe. We're generally not keen here on puzzles that aren't self-contained, though. (Though we have had some that rely on "standard" information sources like, say, Google Maps, like this one: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89135/where-is-it-the-google-earth-challenge-ep-4)

Comment: And there's this one https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49378/a-different-kind-of-treasure-hunt which depends on the exact contents of particular Wikipedia pages at the time of posting. I think we've grown fussier since that was posted and that puzzle would attract some grumpy looks these days.